# Tempo de Vida do Objeto em PHP - Quantas instâncias do Controller?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho um controller que roda o método index para a página principal. Um botão em informações do perfil é chamada por uma rota que cai no método cadastro. A instância que foi executada quando rodou o index ainda existe quando estou executando outro chamado via get? Ou ela se vai a cada novo request?

Answer (score 1):

Tudo depende de como você está programando, pois nada impede de você estar em um controller e enviar uma mensagem para outro, apesar de isto não ser uma boa prática.

Os framewoks que trabalham com MVC, normalmente, tem o seguinte ciclo de vida:
[image: MVC Life Cycle]

Ou seja, por padrão o controller não armazena seu estado de uma requisição para a outra.

Answer (score 0):

O HTTP é um [protocolo sem estado](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocolo_sem_estado).

Resumidamente quer dizer que cada requisição é uma transação independente.

Todo o processo no PHP é compilado em tempo de execução e “morre” quando a compilação está completa.

Numa segunda requisição, inicia-se um novo processo totalmente independente de processos executados em requisições anteriores ou posteriores.

Contudo, há técnicas diversas para manter uma instância “viva” em requisições distintas.

<sub>Obviamente isso não é somente no PHP. É a natureza do protocolo HTTP.</sub>